# Remove white spaces from string in sql

Tags: sql, substring, charindex

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2)
               ,ROUND(  REPLACE
                        (
                          REPLACE(
                                   SUBSTRING([ColumnName],0, CHARINDEX(' ',[ColumnName],1) )
                                   ,'$',''
                                 )
                          ,',',''
                        ) 
                        ,2
                      )
               ) AS 'ColumnName' 
       ,[ColumnName]
       ,* 
FROM TABLENAME
```

The `CHARINDEX` returns index of space, but when there is no space in data it returns `0`. What I want is when ever there is a white space at the end data, `SUBSTRING` should consider that and when there is no white space then it should consider the length of the string.

Comment: Which dbms are you using. (Several product specific functions.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with the last sentence. Can you add some sample data to illustrate? Also, it looks like you're using sql-server (since you use brackets). In sql-server (at least), `substring` is `1` based, not `0` as you are using it.

Comment: to me it reads that you want to remove spaces at the end, if so you can use RTRIM() *on sql server which it looks like you are using*

Answer (score 0):

It seems to you are working with SQL Server, then i would like to apply `case` expression

```
case when CHARINDEX(' ',[ColumnName],1) > 0 
     then CHARINDEX(' ',[ColumnName],1) 
     else len([ColumnName]) end
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're working with sql-server and want to convert a string like `$123,456,789.99` to a `DECIMAL`.

`TRY_PARSE` should get you the result you want:

```
SELECT
TRY_PARSE(REPLACE('$123,456,789.99   ', '$', '')
          AS DECIMAL(18,2)
          USING 'en-US') AS myDecimalNumber
```

Or if it's an option for you to work with the `MONEY` data-type you can omit the `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
TRY_PARSE('$123,456,789.99   '
          AS MONEY
          USING 'en-US')) AS myDecimalNumber
```